# Debugging Rails under ASDF in VSCode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, asdf-vm

I'm trying to set a breakpoint in a Rails application from VSCode on a Mac. I'm using ASDF to install Ruby etc.

The default launch configuration in VSCode for Rails looks like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Rails server",
    "type": "Ruby",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
    "args": [
        "server"
    ]
}
```

That fails because my `which rails` is `Users/timregan/.asdf/shims/rails`. But if I replace `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails"` in the launch.json with `"program": "/Users/timregan/.asdf/shims/rails"` I get this error message when I try to launch a debugging session:

```
    Uncaught exception: /Users/timregan/.asdf/shims/rails:3: unknown regexp options - hbrw
    exec /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/bin/asdf ex...
            ^~~~~~~~~
    /Users/timregan/.asdf/shims/rails:3: syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
    .../opt/asdf/libexec/bin/asdf exec "rails" "$@"
    ...                           ^~~~

        /Users/timregan/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/bin/rdebug-ide:25:in `load'
        /Users/timregan/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/bin/rdebug-ide:25:in `'
```

What is the correct setting to use in VSCode's launch.json to debug Rails when using ASDF?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to ruby interpreting the `.` in `.asdf` or `user.name` as a regular expression and messing up the paths.

What solved it, was adding [binstubs](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-binstubs.1.html) to wrap the real path of the executable (`.../.asdf/.../rspec`) with a `{workspaceFolder}/bin/rspec`

```
bundle binstubs bundler ruby-debug-ide solargraph rspec-core
```

and the binstubs to reference the shimed executables:

```
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/rspec",
      "pathToRDebugIDE": "/${workspaceFolder}/bin/rdebug-ide",
      "pathToBundler": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/bundle",
```

---

Source: Found the solution in this article where you get a step-by-step on setting up your project + launch.json:

https://dev.to/abstractart/easy-way-to-setup-debugger-and-autocomplete-for-ruby-in-visual-studio-code-2gcc

Big kudos to the author